# Print file in particular order in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have file with content:

file.txt:

```
Iteration 1
RAM: +456ms
Cache: +142ms (total +417ms)

Iteration 2
Spec: +152ms
Cache: +149ms (total +413ms)

Iteration 3
RAM: +184ms
Spec: +172ms
Searchms: +131ms (total +385ms)

First launch 4
RAM: +149ms
Searchms: +188ms
```

In this file between every `First launch`, content can be different, it is not fixed ( for example: First launch 3 contain three elements while First launch 2 contents only 2 elements), so any number of content can be between the `First launch` pattern which is not known at the beginning.

Expected Output:

```
RAM  456 184 149
Cache 142 149  
Spec 152 172
Searchms 131 188
```

Due to not knowing exact approach,I have tried this code.

My code:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
awk "/First launch $i/{flag=1;next} /First launch $((i+1))/{flag=0} flag" file.txt> fl$i.txt
sed -i 's/\+//g' fl$i.txt
sed -i 's/://g' fl$i.txt
sed -i 's/(.*//g' fl$i.txt
sed -i 's/ms//g' fl$i.txt
awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}' fl$i.txt
done
```

My output has two issues:
I am generating the file for each pattern which is wrong. Also I wanted to remove  `ms` after the time but it also removes the `ms` from the pattern name (ex: Searchms to Search)

Output:

```
fl1.txt: 
    RAM     456
    Cache   142
fl2.txt : 
    Spec    152
    Cache   149
fl3.txt  :
    RAM     184
    Spec    152
    Search  131
fl4.txt : 
    RAM     149
    Search  188
```

Please suggest me an approach to get the expected output without generating any extra file with the constraint of removing `ms` after the time.

Comment: As an aside, `sed -i s/a/b/' file; sed -i 's/c/d/' file` is better expressed as `sed -i -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/c/d/' file` which only loops across the entire file once.

Comment: do you really want this?  you're losing correlation between the RAM and Cache (and other items), which I assume should be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[: ]+" }
/:/ { vals[$1] = vals[$1] OFS $2+0 }
END { for (key in vals) print key vals[key] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Cache 142 149
RAM 456 184 149
Searchms 131 188
Spec 152 172
```

Comment: Please add some this code is doing and how it helps to solve the question.

Comment: @Selaron Why? It's utterly trivial and extremely clear - what part of it do you not understand after reading the awk documentation?

Comment: Because chances are good this would increase the quality of your post: _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._

Comment: @Selaron No, it would not. Adding a comment to this would be like adding a comment of `incrementing i` to the code `i++`. Please don't rubber-stamp the "**possibly** low quality" flag that some automated tool raises when it sees code-only answers as it's raising that flag for a human who understands the domain to make that determination - if you don't know the domain then don't comment, just move on.

Comment: I [said Looks Ok](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22157792) in the LowQuality queue. Domain knowledge is generally not required to "Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts". For source code only answers I naturally tend to leave a comment. The rest is up to the author. Didn't mean to offend you tho.

Comment: I'm not offended, I'm just providing feedback since it's just a waste of your time posting the comment and mine reading it. Try to shake that natural tendency to always leave a comment on code only answers as they aren't always in need of explanation and most often you'll find answers to the same question on the same page that could benefit far more from [better] explanations than the often trivial and self-explanatory code-only one the tool flags as in this case. I mean just look at this page and you will see other answers that weren't flagged by the tool but are far harder to understand.

Answer (score 5):

One using awk:

```
$ awk '
$1 !~ /^(|First)$/ {            # avoid forbidden keywords and empty lines
    gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$2)        # remove non-numerals
    a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2          # append to associative array 
}
END {                           # in the end
    for(i in a)                 # loop all keywords
        print i a[i]            # output
}' file
```

Output lines in awk default order (appears random):

```
Cache: 142 149
Searchms: 131 188
Spec: 152 172
RAM: 456 184 149
```

Comment: The name ( ex:RAM, Cache,etc.) inside the pattern ' First Launch ' is not known at beginning, it could be any name inside the pattern. I mean it is not hardcoded, it is dynamic.

Comment: Updated to avoid empty records and records starting with `First`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -nE 'if (/^(\w+):\s+\+(\d+)ms/) { push @{$keys{$1}}, $2 } END { while (($k, $vs) = each %keys) { say join(" ", $k, @$vs) }}' file.txt
Spec 152 172
Searchms 131 188
Cache 142 149
RAM 456 184 149
```

(Order of the lines will vary; pipe it to sort if that matters)

---

How it works:

For each line in the file, if it matches the regular expression `^(\w+):\s+\+(\d)ms` (1 or more alphanumeric characters at the start of the line, followed by a colon, whitespace, a plus sign, 1 or more digits, and then the letters m and s), it adds the number to the appropriate array in a hash using the starting word as the key. Then it prints out all those starting words and their associated arrays.

Basically the same idea as the awk answer, but that uses strings instead of arrays because awk doesn't have true arrays like perl, just associative ones (Which are called hashes in perl lingo).

Comment: i don't know the perl language, it could be better if answer is in bash.

Comment: @Arya You'd use that in a shell script.

Comment: Can you please explain the code in brief. It would be easier for me to understand. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @Arya Added a quick explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/:/!d;s/.([0-9]+).*/\1/;H;x;s/((\n\S+) \S+)(.*)\2(.*)/\1\4\3/;h;$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Any lines other than those that contain a `:` are noise, so delete them.

Remove all but the key, a space and the first set of integers from each line.

Append the result to the hold space.

Using pattern matching, gather up like keys data and retain in the hold space.

Delete all but the last line.

At the end of file, swap to the hold space, remove the introduced newline and print the result.

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl, using paragraph mode -00

```
perl -00 -lnE ' 
               while(/(^\S+):.+?(\d+)/gm ) {push(@{$kv{$1}},$2)} 
            END { foreach(keys %kv) { print "$_ @{$kv{$_}}" } }    '
```

with inputs

```
$ cat arya.txt
First launch 1
RAM: +456ms
Cache: +142ms (total +417ms)

First launch 2
Spec: +152ms
Cache: +149ms (total +413ms)

First launch 3
RAM: +184ms
Spec: +172ms
Searchms: +131ms (total +385ms)

First launch 4
RAM: +149ms
Searchms: +188ms

$ perl -00 -lnE ' while(/(^\S+):.+?(\d+)/gm ) {push(@{$kv{$1}},$2)} END { foreach(keys %kv) { print "$_ @{$kv{$_}}" } } ' arya.txt
RAM 456 184 149

Cache 142 149

Searchms 131 188

Spec 152 172


$
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in RAM Cache Spec Searchms; do
    echo "$i `cat file.txt  | grep $i | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,9}' | tr '\n' ' '`" >> out.txt
done
```

You can change the order in line 2 ( for loop )

Output:

```
$ cat out.txt 
RAM 456 184 149 
Cache 142 417 149 413 
Spec 152 172 
Searchms 131 385 188
```