# Mathematical computation in associative array in awk

Tags: arrays, awk

I am following this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599800/10220825 . I want to create an array to store the value of each key and do some mathematical computation like average, maximum, etc.
Here my code:

```
BEGIN { FS="[: ]+"}
/:/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2+0}
END {
         for (key in vals)
         {
                c=0
                sum=0 
                print key vals[key]
                arr[c++]=vals[key]

                for(i=0;i<c;i++)
                {
                        #print arr[0]
                        sum+=sum+arr[i]
                }
                print "Sum = " sum
         }
}
```

But `arr` is not  able to store the individual value of `vals[key]` as it seems `vals[key]` value is stored as string.
Please help me to explore more in an associative array in awk, so that I could store the individual value of vals[key] in array. `For example: for vals[RAM] I could able to create a temporary array to store individual like: arr[0]=142;arr[1]=149;arr[2]=131`. The main purpose for creating a temporary array is to compute mathematical computation like max, min, avg, searching, sorting, etc.

Expected Output:

```
RAM 142 149 131
Sum= 422
Cache 456 152 184
Sum= 792
```

My code output:

```
RAM 142 149 131
Sum= 142
Cache 456 152 184
Sum= 456
```

Comment: This looks like Awk, not Bash.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the sample input that you'd want to get that expected output from. It's fine to reference other questions, etc. but make sure the question makes sense stand-alone.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the sum for each key immediately when you store it seems like a better approach.

```
BEGIN { FS="[: ]+" }
/:/ { vals[$1] = vals[$1] OFS $2+0; sum[$1] +=$ 2+0 }
END { for (key in vals) {
    print key vals[key]
    print "Sum= " sum[key] } }
```

Comment: I want as general way so that i could compute other function like max ,min, avg, sorting,etc.

Comment: Then Awk is not really a suitable tool for this.