# Print file in particular order in awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am following this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599800/10220825

file.txt

```
Iteration 1
RAM: +2s
Cache: +142ms (total +417ms)

Iteration 2
RAM: +184ms
Cache: +172ms
Searchms: +131ms (total +385ms)

Iteration 3
RAM: +149ms
Searchms: +3.2s
```

I want to remove the `ms or s` from the time value but not from name  (example it should not remove Searchms to Search). Also I want to convert `s into ms` by `multiply into 1000` if the time value contains `s` and print result accordingly.

**Expected Output:**

```
RAM: 2000 184 149
Cache: 142 172
Searchms: 131 3200
```

try.awk

```
/:/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2+0}
END {
         for (key in vals)
          print key vals[key]
}
```

On executing : `awk -f try.awk file.txt`

**Code Output:**

```
Cache: 142 172
Searchms: 131 3.2
RAM: 2 184 149
```

In my output `s is not converting to ms.` Please suggest me how I modify above source code `try.awk` to convert s to ms.

---

New Test Case:
**file.txt**

```
Iteration 1
RAM: +2s342ms

Iteration 2
RAM: +2s

Iteration 3
RAM: +149ms
```

Code:

```
/:/ && $2 ~/ms$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2+0;next}
/:/ && $2 ~/[^m]s$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS ($2+0)*1000}
END {
         for (key in vals)
          print key vals[key]
}
```

Expected output:

```
RAM: 2342 2000 149
```

Output:

```
RAM: 2 2000 149
```

Comment: Remember `awk` is _not_ `bash`

Comment: Do you want the final result in `ms` or `s`? If in `s`, you are most likely to do `/1000`

Comment: The previous answers you received to your questions demonstrated how to do this many times. Perhaps a quick review of an Awk tutorial would be in order at this point.

Comment: @triplee, Yes i would sure.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` script:

```
/:/ && $2 ~/ms$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2+0;next}
/:/ && $2 ~/[^m]s$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS ($2+0)*1000}
END {
         for (key in vals)
          print key vals[key]
}
```

This will produce the output:

```
awk -f try.awk file.txt 
Cache: 142 172
Searchms: 131 3200
RAM: 2000 184 149
```

**Explanations:**

- The condition `$2 ~/ms$/` will check if we have a line with `ms` in this case the same logic is done as before and the `next` will force `awk` to jump to the next line.
- `/:/ && $2 ~/[^m]s$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS ($2+0)*1000}` when we reach this scope we know that we have a line with units in `s` and we multiply it by 1000 to convert it to `ms`.

To answer to your new requirements, I have adapted the `try.awk` into:

```
/:/ && $2 ~/[0-9]+s[0-9]+ms$/{split($2,buff,/s/);vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS (buff[1]+0)*1000+buff[2];next}
/:/ && $2 ~/ms$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2+0;next}
/:/ && $2 ~/[^m]s$/{vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS ($2+0)*1000}
END {
         for (key in vals)
          print key vals[key]
}
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat file2.txt 
Iteration 1
RAM: +2s342ms

Iteration 2
RAM: +2s

Iteration 3
RAM: +149ms
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk -f try.awk file2.txt 
RAM: 2342 2000 149
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/1000`? It is `ms` -> `s`

Comment: @Inian: I am converting `s` -> `ms` as requested by OP.

Comment: @Allan, Your code is not working for test case if we have mixed of `s` and `ms`. Please see the updated test case above

Comment: @Arya: I have adapted my code to your new requirements, could you please test my new answer?

Answer (score 2):

A small adaptation of the OP:

```
/:/{  vals[$1]=vals[$1] OFS $2*($2~/ms$/ ? 1 : 1000 ) }
END { for (key in vals) print key vals[key] }
```

Remark: this will not work on all versions of awk, this makes use of the following nifty feature of gawk (and POSIX):

> A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix of the string as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3" converts to 1,000, **and "25fix" has a numeric value of 25**. Strings that can’t be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.
>
> **<sub>source: [Gnu Awk manual: Conversion of Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conversion)</sub>**

This behaviour is Posix valid and works using the C-function `atof`. POSIX, however, gives a second option to convert strings to numbers where "25fix" would convert to 0. This is, for example, the case on Oracle:

```
Linux: GNU $ awk 'BEGIN{print "25fix"+0}'
25
SUN OS: SUNWesu $ /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{print "25fix"+0}'
0
SUN OS: SUNWxpg $ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{print "25fix"+0}'
25
```